# Windsor dependency injection with parameter in ctor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I'm trying to configure Castle Windsor

I have a IFileReader interface implemented by FileReader, and FileReader has a string property in the constructor

How can I set this property when I'm trying to get an instance of FileReader with a ServiceLocator?

```
Container.Register(Component.For<IFileReader>().ImplementedBy<FileReader>());

public class FileReader
{
public FileReader(string fileName)
.
.
.

ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IFileReader>(); <- how pass filename??
```

Comment: Best option: don't use the container as a Service Locator at all: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were having a discussion in the Alt.Net Hispano group about this topic.

Here is the link (spanish) if anyone is interested
http://groups.google.com/group/altnet-hispano/browse_thread/thread/5880f9e9fe5b5da4/200443a0b9e99040?show_docid=200443a0b9e99040

Basically, you can't do what I want to do :P

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Inline-Dependencies.ashx) shall help you.

In a few words, you can use `DependsOn`, `ServiceOverrides`, `Parameters` or `DynamicParameters`. Select the one that is best suitable for you.